# PHP Access Database with GET Security

Tags: php, database, security, get

I am writing a database interface using PHP.  One of the functions of the database is to allow members to login and register for events online.  I would like to create a php file that would create a dynamic calendar file users can subscribe to.  Something to the effect of www.hostname.net/my_calendar.php?memid=123.  The file then will search the database for events member 123 has registered for and create a calendar file on the fly.  My concern the security of using the members' id number for this purpose.  Is there a good way of accomplishing this with a reasonable amount of security, or may there be a security issue here that I am not considering.

Comment: What are you trying to protect and from whom?  Is the member ID easily guessable (a serial number for example) or are member IDs generated by a crytographically strong random number generator?

Comment: That is a good question, and honestly I am not sure I have a good answer.  I don't care if someone can see what events I registered for, but someone else might.  Member IDs are a unique randomly generated 6 digit number.

Comment: until you know what you're protecting, you cannot say what is safe or unsafe.  I would start by trying to keep private whatever a reasonable user is going to assume is private.  If you have a large enough random number then an attacker has to do a lot of work to find valid IDs so you can rely on the randomness to prevent guessing, but 6 decimal digits just is not big enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try hashing some of your user's public details. For example, you can merge the user's first/last names and his `user_id` with this method http://blog.kevburnsjr.com/php-unique-hash. That will generate a hash something like `cJio3`. The `user_id` will be obfuscated. This won't stop any hackers from getting in, but will slow them down. :)

Comment: This is what I was leaning toward; I just wasn't sure how much this would sacrifice efficiency.  But I guess security is always going to sacrifice efficiency to some degree.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to do `my_calendar.php?memid=123`. If the user is logged in, you will be tracking his user id, either via session, or a cookie. Thus, you can just `/my_calendar.php`. This way, a user cannot attempt to view someone else's calendar.

Comment: Generally, I do use session variables for keeping users logged in, but I want the user to be able to subscribe to the calendar, so when they are not logged in, their calendar (e.g. Outlook, iCal, etc.) can update based on other events they register for, or changes the coordinator makes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't link there would be any security concerns, but **it depends on what an mallicious user can do with that id.**
StackOverflow for expample does also use the user id for their profile like [https://stackoverflow.com/users/**808723**/gamescripting](https://stackoverflow.com/users/808723/gamescripting).

If you want the user only to see its own events then [follow the approach xbonez suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13112173/808723).